# Android periipheral mode detection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, mode, peripherals, broadcom

Can anyone please tel me ,is there any possibility to check in which mode(i.e. central or peripheral mode), the BLE is operating? If so on what basis can we find out. I am using BCM20702. It says it supports both modes. But is there a way in which we can find out as to which mode is the device working in?

Regards,

Sathya

Answer (score 0):

If you are advertising, you're a Peripheral. If you are scanning and initiating connections, you're a Central. It's as simple as that.